# Texts overlap problem

Tags: html, css

I have three links on my page:

```
<a class="contact" href="../contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a> 
<a class="car" href="../car.html" target="_blank">Car</a> 
<a class="market" href="../market.html" target="_blank">Market</a>
```

I CSS them as below:

```
a.car{
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  right: 10%;
  margin-top:10px;
}

a.market{
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  margin-top:10px;



}
```

As the browser window size changing smaller, the three link texts get **overlaped** at some point, how to resolve this? I mean how to make the link texts not overlapping when browser window size get smaller?

Comment: @DanielB, I want to resolve the problem so that the link texts are not overlapping when browser window get smaller

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
position: absolute;
```

and specifying `left` attribute. If you want the links in a row, use the css as

```
a.menuitem {
  float:left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
div.clearer { clear:both; }
```

and use the menuitem class in all a's and declare a clearer after the menu is over.

```
<a class="contact menuitem" href="../contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a> 
<a class="car menuitem" href="../car.html" target="_blank">Car</a> 
<a class="market menuitem" href="../market.html" target="_blank">Market</a> 
<div class="clearer" ></div>
```

Comment: You made the link text unclickable

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the css that you want...

```
a.contact{
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;

  margin-left: 20%;
  right: 10%;
  margin-top:10px;
}

a.car{
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;


  right: 10%;
  margin-top:10px;
}

a.market{
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;


  margin-top:10px;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your links to `display:block;` to get them away from the Contact link and then change your `position` from a fluid `%` to a static `px` like

```
a.car{
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  margin-top:10px;
  display:block;  
}

a.market{
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  margin-top:10px;
  display:block;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/qAKvQ/